# How to identify two error messages with different elements and write the data to excel in Data driven framework

Tags: python, selenium, if-statement, data-driven-tests

I'm new to Selenium /Python, I have Login validation. when user try to login, if password is **Invalid** or **expired** it will display 2 error message with different location. data is coming from excel with for loop. (Data driven framework).

If login password is **expired** it is working fine. the its moving to next, **if password is invalid still its checking password expired condition only** and exist the loop and give 'error'. It's not going through `elif` or `else`.

```py
    print("Login Pass")
else:
    time.sleep(5)
    try:
        if (self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                self.lp.textbox_ConfirmPassword_xpath).is_displayed() == True) \
                or (self.lp.verifyInvalidPasswordIsDisplay() == "Invalid username or password"):
            if self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.lp.textbox_ConfirmPassword_xpath).is_displayed():
                self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.lp.textbox_ConfirmPassword_xpath).click()
                print("expired")
                XLUtils.writeData(self.path, 'Sheet2', r, 6, 'Expired password')
            elif self.lp.verifyInvalidPasswordIsDisplay() == "Invalid username or password":
                print("invalid")
                XLUtils.writeData(self.path, 'Sheet2', r, 3, 'Invalid username or password')
            else:
                XLUtils.writeData(self.path, 'Sheet2', r, 4, 'Error')

        else:
            print("error")
    except NoSuchElementException:
        XLUtils.writeData(self.path, 'Sheet2', r, 4, 'Error')
    print(self.user)
    print("login fail")
self.driver.close()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Sheni, I've answered your question. Please take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not going through `elif self.lp.verifyInvalidPasswordIsDisplay() == "Invalid username or password":`
nor the `else`, is because in all conditions, the first nested `if` (the one statement which **only** checks the `self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.lp.textbox_ConfirmPassword_xpath).is_displayed()`) is `True` and it won't go through other `elif` nor `else` statements.

The first `if` (which contains the `if-elif-else statements`) ,has a condition like this:

```py
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                self.lp.textbox_ConfirmPassword_xpath).is_displayed() == True
```

However it is followed by the other condition with `or` but it seems in all situations the `textbox_ConfirmPassword_xpath` is `True`.

Since this condition is exactly repeated in the first nested `if`, and therefore the condition of this `if` statement is always `True` and it won't let other conditions to be checked.

First of all, in my opinion the first `if` is not necessary and you could just do the work without it, like this:

```py
    print("Login Pass")
else:
    time.sleep(5)
    try:
        
        if self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.lp.textbox_ConfirmPassword_xpath).is_displayed():
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.lp.textbox_ConfirmPassword_xpath).click()
            print("expired")
            XLUtils.writeData(self.path, 'Sheet2', r, 6, 'Expired password')
        elif self.lp.verifyInvalidPasswordIsDisplay() == "Invalid username or password":
            print("invalid")
            XLUtils.writeData(self.path, 'Sheet2', r, 3, 'Invalid username or password')
        else:
            XLUtils.writeData(self.path, 'Sheet2', r, 4, 'Error')
            print('error')

    except NoSuchElementException:
        XLUtils.writeData(self.path, 'Sheet2', r, 4, 'Error')
    print(self.user)
    print("login fail")
self.driver.close()
```

---

Secondly, you should choose a better condition for the first `if` instead of `self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.lp.textbox_ConfirmPassword_xpath).is_displayed()`, since as I said before, apparently in all cases this condition is `True`.

---

Moreover, I suggest to use `Constants` to check the equality of error messages, for example:
Instead of `"Invalid username or password"` string, do this:

```py
INVALID_USERNAME_PASS = "Invalid username or password"
.
.
.
self.lp.verifyInvalidPasswordIsDisplay() == INVALID_USERNAME_PASS: 
   # DO STUFF
```

Because, in this way it's more `maintainable` and it's not `hard coded` any more.